# Consolidate 650 worksheets in the same workbook down to one page

Tags: excel, vba

This code gives me everything from all the sheets and not even in a way that columns are matched up.  I made a VBA script the took all 127 individual excell sheets and combined them into one workbook with 600+ sheets.  I want only the 127 sheets called "Function Dependency" numbered blank - 127 to be combined into one sheet.  The columns sometimes have useless data in the first row but otherwise have similar columns.  Is there a better way to do this??

```
Sub MergeAll()
Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet, rAll As Long, wsAll As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.name = "All"
Set wsAll = ActiveSheet
rAll = 2
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.name <> "All" Then
    r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To r
        wsAll.Cells(rAll, 1) = ws.name
        wsAll.Cells(rAll, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        wsAll.Cells(rAll, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 2)
        rAll = rAll + 1
    Next i
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: If this works, and you're looking to make it more efficient, you should perhaps instead post over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It DOES do part of the work.  I combines 650 sheets into one nonsense sheet with 10k rows.  But i need it to be more selective of what sheets it pulls from and i need it to line the data up for me.  All sheets have similar columns.

Comment: I echo the code review recommendation of @BruceWayne . As to your actual question " Is there a better way to do this??" the answer is a very emphatic yes. Your code is extremely inefficient, iterating through hundreds of sheets on a cell-by-cell basis. A well-written version of this code will be at least an order of magnitude quicker

Comment: Ok ill look for that area and try there.  I'm very green to this VBA stuff and to stack overflow.  MY java teacher suggested this site but not where to get things done.  Thanks

Comment: This is a fantastic site, no doubt there. The "trick" to SO is that it's generally for specific questions, which can have specific answers.  It took me a while to get the hang of what questions are "good" here. Keep searching around, make some attempts at your question, then when you get stuck, you are free to ask a specific question.  It also helps to see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Welcome to SO, and hopefully you stick around! :D

Comment: `If ws.name Like "Function Dependency*" Then` will only copy from the sheets you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub MergeAll()

    Dim r As Long, ws As Worksheet, rAll As Long, wsAll As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set wsAll = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    wsAll.name = "All"

    rAll = 2
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.name Like "Function Dependency*" Then

            r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To r

                wsAll.Cells(rAll, 1).Resize(1, 3).value = _
                      Array(ws.name, ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 2))

                rAll = rAll + 1
            Next i

        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The only thing left is to figure out why im only getting 2 or 3 rows from each chart. Thanks for the help tim :)

Comment: You're checking the number of rows in each sheet by looking at ColA - if there are blank cells in there you may be missing some rows.